# Xamarin UWP app not restricting the user from resizing the window to lower size in 150(recommended) resolution

Tags: windows, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

```
     protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
            { 
              
             Window.Current.SizeChanged += Current_SizeChanged;
            }
    


    private void Current_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
            if (displayInformation.ResolutionScale == ResolutionScale.Scale125Percent || displayInformation.ResolutionScale == ResolutionScale.Scale100Percent)
            {
                var screenSize = new Size(displayInformation.ScreenWidthInRawPixels,
                                          displayInformation.ScreenHeightInRawPixels);
                var minheight = screenSize.Height * 0.7;
                var minwidth = screenSize.Width * 0.7;
                if (e.Size.Height < minheight || e.Size.Width < minwidth)
                {
                    ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(new Size(minwidth, minheight));
                }
            }
    else{
    //150 and above resolution
var screenSize = new Size(displayInformation.ScreenWidthInRawPixels,
                           displayInformation.ScreenHeightInRawPixels);
            var minwidth = screenSize.Width / 1.5;
                 if (e.Size.Width < minwidth)
                {
                    var size = new Size(1100, 640);
                    ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(size);
                    Debug.WriteLine("resize staus: " + ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(size));
                }

           
        }
```

The above code is working fine in 100 and 125 resolution. But in 150(recommended) resolution user is able to minimize the application to lower size. Any idea how to handle the screen size on 150 resolution.

Comment: @Nico Zhu - MSFT I am testing in different resolution. I have little concern on hard coding as var size = new Size(600, 640)(rather than than finding the available work area);  post that I will make this as accepted. Thanks!..

Comment: When you maximize the window, you could get the VisibleBounds with ` ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds`. and the height of current window is the max work area height (656.66). but it can't work for `TryResizeView` method. and after testing allow max height is 640.66.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I think that is okay .But today got a weird issue, the above code is working fine in debug mode in all machine but when I took a build in release mode, its allowing me to resize the width lesser than the minimum . I don't know what is going wrong and how to debug.

Comment: So, what's the minimum size you used in the release model?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT  I updated my code.. Since in 600 width my UI is getting distorted  I increase to 1100 width(because we have an available work area of 1280,600). Its working perfectly in debug mode but not in release.

Comment: I have tested with `var size = new Size(1260, 600); `,  it works well in release model.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT anyway I can see TryResizeView() result in release mode or any way to debug release build?. Since it is happening at the very beginning of the application I am not able to add the logs.

Comment: The better way is use AppCenter to report the log when app runs in the release model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.setpreferredminsize?view=winrt-19041) document.

> The smallest allowed minimum size is 192 x 48 effective pixels. The largest allowed minimum size is 500 x 500 effective pixels. If you set a value outside of these bounds, it is coerced to be within the allowed bounds. (To learn about effective pixels, see Introduction to Windows app design.)

So, please edit your largest width 150 to 192.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   
var size = new Size(192, 150);
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(size);
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(size);

}
```

If you want to set current windows size as 150*150, please set the `ApplicationViewMode` as `CompactOverlay` the give it `CustomSize` like the following

```
var preferences = ViewModePreferences.CreateDefault(ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay);
preferences.CustomSize = new Windows.Foundation.Size(150, 150);
await ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterViewModeAsync(ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay, preferences);
```

**Update**

please check this remark [part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryresizeview?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.TryResizeView)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore%2CVersion%253Dv5.0)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=winrt-19041#remarks)

> The requested size is larger than the available work area (no effect);

1920*1080 Scale150Percent, available work area is 1280 * (720 - taskbarheight). when you set 600 * 800,  `TryResizeView` has no effect. Because the app's window has larger than current work are. Please try to set it as 600 * 600.

Update 1

> now its not allowing the user to shrink or restore down below 600,600. But the issue now is, its not allowing to maximize or expand more than 600,600 as well.

Please add the maximize window width trigger condition like the following.

```
var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
if (displayInformation.ResolutionScale == ResolutionScale.Scale125Percent || displayInformation.ResolutionScale == ResolutionScale.Scale100Percent)
{
    var screenSize = new Size(displayInformation.ScreenWidthInRawPixels,
                              displayInformation.ScreenHeightInRawPixels);
    var minheight = screenSize.Height * 0.7;
    var minwidth = screenSize.Width * 0.7;
    if (e.Size.Height < minheight || e.Size.Width < minwidth)
    {
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(new Size(minwidth, minheight));
    }
}
else
{
    var screenSize = new Size(displayInformation.ScreenWidthInRawPixels,
                                displayInformation.ScreenHeightInRawPixels);
    var minwidth = screenSize.Width / 1.5;
    if (e.Size.Width < minwidth)
    {
        var size = new Size(600, 640);         
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(size);
    }
    //150 resolution
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To make some more clear I have added more codes to my question. I want to restrict the user from resizing the window screen below around 600,800 size. Currently I am launching the application on full size(not in full screen mode because I don't want to hide my taskbar).once the user click minimize or shrink the application window size, I need to restrict him till around 600,800 size.

Comment: Ok. I got it, please check this remark [part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryresizeview?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.TryResizeView)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore%2CVersion%253Dv5.0)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=winrt-19041#remarks)  The requested size is larger than the available work area (no effect);

Comment: 1920*1080 Scale150Percent  available work area is 1280*720. when you set 600*800,  `TryResizeView` has no effect.

Comment: @ Nico Zhu - MSFT Thanks !... now its  not allowing the user to shrink or restore down below 600,600. But the issue now is, its not allowing to maximize or  expand more than 600,600 as well.

Comment: Please check update 1 part, and add the trigger condition.

Comment: One last thing, instead of hard coding size as (600,640) is there any way we can find the available work area for different resolution? then it should work for all the user .

Comment: When you maximize the app window you could get the size of current work area in SizeChanged  `var size = e.Size`.(1280*648).